# find subsets in python that sum less than or equal a target value

Tags: python, algorithm

I've seen different variations of this problem and I am unable to get a solution to this particular one: "Given a list of positive integers and a target t, find all maximal subsets whose sum is less than or equal to t. Each element must appear only as many times as they appear in the given input list"

For eg: If the list is `[1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1]` and `target = 6`:

one possible output: `[[1,2,2,1], [3, 3], [5], [5]]`
another possible output: `[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [5], [5]`

There maybe other possibilities as well..

Looks like a nice greedy approach can solve this problem...but, I am unable to write a soln in Python. When I say 'maximal' subset, the system must try to find subsets preferably of largest size possible...rather than choosing smaller-sized subsets. Any help?

- go through in a greedy manner and add elements in a bag as we see fit (as close to target value ...).
- remove elements already bagged.
- take a new bag now.
- repeat the above two steps until all elements are bagged.

NOTE: i am not looking for computationally efficient soln. I am looking for 'a' solution that works. The given list is small in size...perhaps a max of 100 elements.

Comment: What about `[1, 2, 2, 1]`?

Comment: Sorry...missed that. I have edited the original post to reflect `[1,2,2,1]`.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tio.run/##VZDBbsMgEETv/oo5QoMqOVF6sJovsXzAySZFwYCWTeV@vWsct3VXHJbVvGGW9CUfMRym6UJX5Og/SXkDsXwj0U2Fua4cBzghlhh9hhtSZME5Dr0LVlwMeZExZZzQdk8mMhxcANtwI1UbeArKa@xQr7alesryB/2AYwG3/iWS22Cl3Bz3MajioPG@9OPcnNbs/8Wbt8Zq41BmTUn@alOicFHtSxl1@ldEPlODnsne1y3lwaEgVZXYBVHPT2vnFQ8GR4P9co7Lte4M3rSepm8) work for you?

Comment: @Unmitigated The items in each subset must not repeat. That is, the items can appear only as many times as they appear in the original list. No more, no less. Eg: here, 15 must appear only twice in the output...and 28 only once.

print(solve([15, 28, 89, 95, 272, 23, 80, 100, 15, 26], 300))
output: [[272], [28, 272], [89, 95, 100], [15, 89, 95, 100], [15, 89, 80, 100, 15], [15, 28, 95, 23, 100, 26], [15, 28, 89, 23, 100, 15, 26]]

Comment: In the example in the question, `2` appears 2 times in the input but 4 times in the output - is there another rule at play here?

Comment: @user1717931 The criteria are not clear then. Why does 272 appear twice, for instance?

Comment: What is the question about, exactly? Do you not know how to solve it at all, is your solution not optimal or what? Have you tried anything?

Comment: An error from my side. Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the example. thanks for catching the error in the eg output. The key here is that the items must appear only as many times as they appear in the original input list. No less, no more.

Comment: Again in the example in the question, what criterion makes `[1,2,2,1], [3,3], [5], [5]` the correct answer rather than `[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [5], [5]` ?

Comment: And, yes, I did try a basic non-recursive version (chose non-recursive..to avoid hitting recursive depth issues). I do not know how to modify the original array as and when I find a suitable subset and try to remove those items from the original array and find another subset....

Comment: Would just `my_list.remove(x}` not work to remove the items? (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) It's not the most computationally efficient way, but that ought to work if performance isn't a big deal.

Comment: The output `[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [5], [5]` is also fine with me. But, I do not want a solution that has all sublists of size 1.

Comment: OK, sorry, this just doesn't seem a precisely specified problem. What if you sort the list and iterate through it, adding elements to each sublist for as long as they don't exceed the target. Does that seem like an acceptable solution?

Comment: Your example doesn't match your problem description. You're supposed to find subsets. In what sense is `[[1,2,2,1], [3, 3], [5], [5]]` a subset?

Comment: @slothrop Do you sort the list ascending or descending?  When you reach the end of the list below the target, should that be included or not.  (At least sometimes it has to be - for example if the sum of the whole list is below the target.)

Comment: @btilly I was assuming "ascending" and "yes" respectively, which would give the acceptable solution `[[1,1,2,2], [3,3], [5], [5]]`. However a more detailed specification of the problem might well throw up more complexities

Comment: @KellyBundy My understanding is that the input list represents a multiset, and the output should be a list of submultisets. @ the OP: it would be great if you could confirm.

Comment: @Stef I understand the example's input and output. The output just isn't what the problem description asks for.

Comment: My impression is that OP has a real-world problem for which a heuristic "good-enough" solution would work, rather than needing to rigorously solve a well-defined mathematical problem. But let's see!

Comment: I liked @slothrop solution of first sorting it and just going on in a greedy way to pack elements and removing from the active-list (sorting did not come to my mind at all!!) . I totally understand the "looseness" of the problem statement and the confusion it brought when I put in a sample output (and changed it a few times). I do agree the outputs could be different. Again, slothrop's solution is good-enough for me. We can close this effort now. Thanks to all who jumped in (and sorry for all the chaos...).

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive generator:

```py
def get_subsets(items, target):
    items = sorted(items)
    def helper(i, t, acc):
        if i >= len(items): # no more items
            return
        elif items[i] > t: # all remaining items are too big
            yield acc
        else:
            yield from helper(i+1, t - items[i], (*acc, items[i])) # include item[i]
            yield from helper(i+1, t, acc)                  # do not include item[i]
    yield from helper(0, target, ())

print(list(get_subsets([1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1], 6)))
# [(1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2,), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2,), (3, 3), (3,), (3,), (5,)]
```